# checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... NOTE Maintainer

Tags: r, cran, r-package

When I run `R CMD check --as-cran`  on my package, the one note I still get is:

```
checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... NOTE 
Maintainer:[my name] <my email>
```

I can't seem to find a good explanation of this note, although I haven't read anything that tells my I should be concerned about it.  As anyone else run into this?  Is there anything I can do that will clear the note?

Comment: Just ignore it. :) See also [this post](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/NOTE-when-checking-CRAN-income-feasibility-td4685938.html)

Comment: And [here](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15371) and [here](https://mailman.stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2014-March/068497.html)

Comment: I've gotten really good at ignoring things since I had kids. This I can do.  Thanks.

Comment: @gagolews, post summaries of those threads as an answer?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

[According to](https://mailman.stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2014-March/068497.html) CRAN Maintainer Uwe Ligges,

> *This is just a note that reminds CRAN maintainers to check that the 
>   submission comes actually from his maintainer and not anybody else.*

Thus, it is safe to ignore such a message.

Answer (score 4):

These checks can be disabled. R Internals states:

```
_R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_

Check whether package is suitable for publication on CRAN. Default: false, except for CRAN submission checks.

_R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_REMOTE_

Include checks that require remote access among the above. Default: same as _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_
```

Answer (score -3):

I usually run M-x occur  [^OK]$ and scoll through the 'occur' buffer. Hope that helps

Comment: is this something to do with Emacs? I don't see any reference to that in the question