# A warning which doesn't show up in the R CMD check results: 1 warning or 0 warnings?

Tags: r, build, package, warnings

I'm building an R package under Windows 10 with RStudio 1.0.136 and get a warning about `qpdf` (see [How to build qpdf on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570633/how-to-build-qpdf-on-windows) for more details about this issue). But and the end of the checks, the number of warnings is shown to be 0. So I wonder if there is one or no warning that has to be solved before I can submit the package to CRAN?

---

Here is the last part of the checks:

...

- checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK
  WARNING
  'qpdf' is needed for checks on size reduction of PDFs
- checking installed files from 'inst/doc' ... OK
- checking files in 'vignettes' ... OK
- checking examples ... OK
- checking for unstated dependencies in vignettes ... OK
- checking package vignettes in 'inst/doc' ... OK
- checking re-building of vignette outputs ... OK
- DONE
  Status: 1 WARNING

See
  'C:/Users/username/Documents/hmi.Rcheck/00check.log'
for details.

R CMD check results
0 errors | 0 warnings | 0 notes

R CMD check succeeded

Comment: I get this every time I check my packages on my local machine.  I also submit the packages to CRAN's win-builder.  If I don't see the warning on win-builder, I don't worry about it. (Not a very robust system, admittedly, and probably ripe for criticism)

Comment: Well, you could install qpdf ... Binaries appear to be available.

Comment: I've downloaded https://sourceforge.net/projects/qpdf/files/qpdf/6.0.0/qpdf-6.0.0-bin-mingw64.zip/download and unzipped it. But it still doesn't work. I guess because I unzipped it into the wrong folder. But I couldn't figure out the correct folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @Benjamin, I've uploaded my `.tar.gz`-file to the  [win-builder](https://win-builder.r-project.org/) (with [this nice upload-tool](https://win-builder.r-project.org/upload.aspx)). The `00check.log`-file now says

...

- checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK
- checking installed files from 'inst/doc' ... OK

...

So the answer to my question is, that the warning about qpdf apparently can be ignored.

---

The only NOTE I get is (here I've anonymised my name and email-adress) :

```
* checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... NOTE
Maintainer: 'My Name <blob@domain.com>'
```

And this seems to be an ignorable issue ([checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... NOTE Maintainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829978/checking-cran-incoming-feasibility-note-maintainer)).