# note when sending new version of package to cran "checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... Note_to_CRAN_maintainers" wont let me send it to CRAN

Tags: r, package, cran

I am aware that this issue has been answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829978/checking-cran-incoming-feasibility-note-maintainer), and that I am supposed to ignore that message, however, when I send the package to cran I get an automatic response from Uwe Ligges stating:

Dear maintainer,

package NetworkExtinction_0.1.1.tar.gz does not pass the incoming checks automatically, please see the following pre-tests:
Windows: <https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/NetworkExtinction_0.1.1_20191026_190159/Windows/00check.log>
Status: 1 NOTE

If you check that link, you will see that the only note I get is:

```
* checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... Note_to_CRAN_maintainers
Maintainer: 'Derek Corcoran <derek.corcoran.barrios@gmail.com>'
```

Any idea on how I can pass that note? I have seen that many developers have had that problem, should I reply that I think is a false positive?

Many Thanks

Comment: Hi Derek, I am now facing the same problem - did you eventually manage to solve the issue?

Comment: I did solve it, let me check it out and I will answer tomorrow

Comment: I though that this issue is not matter but I am facing this now when I submit to CRAN. That is the only note returned but the package did not pass.

Comment: My experience was after all that I got an email from the CRAN team that stated that my package did not pass due to the mentioned reason. Around a day later I got a second email that asked me to reduce the run-time of my unit tests, which I did, resubmitted and eventually passed. So my prior would be that you will go through a similar procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Though the email you get points you to the log, and this contains only a
`Note_to_CRAN_maintainers` warning, if you look at the bottom of the email, "CRAN teams' auto-check service", there will typically be a problem raised.

The common problem that doesn't appear in the log is the overall check time.

This is usually driven by long examples (manually need to find these) or lengthy tests... Just have to cut or remove test files to speed checking on the overburdened CRAN machines.

> Flavor: r-devel-windows-x86_64
> Check: Overall checktime, Result: NOTE
> Overall checktime 20 min > 10 min

> Flavor: r-devel-linux-x86_64-debian-gcc
> Check: CRAN incoming feasibility, Result: Note_to_CRAN_maintainers
> Maintainer: 'Youan me you@me.com'