# R package declaring author in DESCRIPTION

Tags: r, r-package

My DESCRIPTION file looks like this (showing only relevant part).

```
Author: John Doe
Authors@R: person("John", "Doe", email = "john.doe@email.com",role = c("aut", "cre"))
Maintainer: John Doe <john.doe@email.com>
```

`devtools::check()`, `R CMD check` and `R CMD build` completes fine. But, CRAN submission returns this NOTE:

```
  * checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... NOTE
Author field differs from that derived from Authors@R
Author:    'John Doe'
Authors@R: 'John Doe [aut, cre]'
```

Not sure what that's about. Anyway, checking [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file), it says:

> Fields ‘Author’ and ‘Maintainer’ can be auto-generated from ‘Authors@R’, and may be omitted if the latter is provided.

So, I removed Author and maintainer. Now when I run `R CMD check` locally:

```
* checking for file ‘./DESCRIPTION’ ... ERROR
Required fields missing or empty:
  ‘Author’ ‘Maintainer’
```

What's the best way to do this?

**UPDATE**

I removed `Authors@R` and left `Author` and `Maintainer` as is. All local tests passed. But, CRAN complaints about this.

```
* checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... NOTE
Maintainer: 'John Doe <john.doe@email.com>'
```

But, I don't get this.

**UPDATE**

This issue has been documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829978/checking-cran-incoming-feasibility-note-maintainer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either use Author and Maintainer or Authors@R. In the latter case I would leave out Author and Maintainer, since these are populated by `R CMD build`. This brings me to the most important point: Never run `R CMD check` on a source directory but only on the `tar.gz` created by `R CMD build`!

Otherwise you will get strange warnings due to unusual files (`.Rbuildignore` is not taken into account), the existence of object files in `src`, ....

BTW, using `devtools::check()` is fine from my experience, but it is always good to know what is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `R CMD check .` does not compile the `Authors@R` field. Running `R CMD build .` then `R CMD check mypkg.tar.gz` seems to better reproduce what happens on build systems. I also like using `devtools::check()` as it rebuilds roxygen documentation before running check.

btw I think instead of `John Doe [aut, cre]` you should use `person("John", "Doe", role = c("aut", "cre"))`, per the documentation you linked.

Comment: `John Doe [aut, cre]` was not my doing. I assumed it was done by CRAN. But, perhaps it was done by `R CMD build` when I created the tarball. I have removed `Authors@R` altogether. I am hoping just the `Author` and `Maintainer` should work.

Comment: My bad, I missed that you had person calls in Authors@R. Why do you need `R CMD check` anyway? Why not just set up continuous integration?

Comment: So the package installs fine locally and from Github. Everything regarding using the package works. Issues are with submission to CRAN. Not sure if CI is relevant for CRAN submission.

Comment: Installation from github works fine with Authors@R. Installing locally as well (`devtools::install` or `R CMD build`). CI is a good idea if you expect people to install from github to ensure master always works.