# What does CRAN mean by "significant notes"?

Tags: r, cran

In [CRAN Repository Policy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html) they write:

> In principle, packages must pass R CMD check without warnings or significant notes to be admitted to the main CRAN package area.

The term "significant notes" appears a bit vague. Any idea what do they mean by this in practice? Or perhaps the question should be turned, what is an "insignificant note" in R CMD check allowing publication on CRAN?

I have a feeling that "significant notes" might be those they mention indirectly (package size and processing time of examples). I still feel a bit confused by this term. [Hadley Wickham explains that each note](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/check.html) has to be manually checked by a person and therefore notes should either be eliminated or mentioned in [the submission comments](https://cran.r-project.org/submit.html). The whole point is to save the time of volunteers, which is "CRAN’s most precious resource", they write. Following this instruction, it would be nice to know which R CMD notes will definitely lead to the rejection of a package.

Comment: Also relevant for the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439256/how-can-i-handle-r-cmd-check-no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-notes-when

Comment: Assume everything

Comment: @HongOoi except for the maintainer note? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829978/checking-cran-incoming-feasibility-note-maintainer